# gltf2.0 not showing in ar.js project

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I have created an ar.js tryout page like this:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>


<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>

<!-- handle marker with hiro preset -->
<a-marker preset='hiro'>
  <a-entity 
  gltf-model-next="src:url(lugia_pokemon/scene.gltf)"
  position="0 0 0"
  scale="1 1 1"></a-entity>
  <!-- <a-image src="corvette_stingray/image.jpg"></a-text> -->
  <!-- <a-text value="Hello" color="red"></a-text> -->
</a-marker>

<!-- <a-marker preset='hiro'></a-marker>
    <a-text value="Hello, this is Enze'a first AR try!" color="red"></a-text>
</a-marker> -->

<!-- add a simple camera -->
<a-entity camera></a-entity>
```

It is not working after I launch the html file. The gltf is in the folder with .bin under the same dir of the html. Running on localhost with npm http-server also not working as implied by the console. But if I change the entity to something like text or a-box it does show. Also for a-image it only show a white box without any image.

Also when I open with my phone it cannot get the permission of webcam but when open https://codepen.io/jeromeetienne/pen/mRqqzb   my phone chrome app will ask for the permission of camera and open and work.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your scene with `<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; trackingMethod: best;' antialias='true' gesture-detector>` it will help you get everything more aligned. Also, try to separate the asset declaration from its use:

```
<a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="gltf=model" src="YOUR_SRC"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<a-marker preset='hiro'>
    <a-gltf-model src="#gltf-model" scale="1 1 1" position="0 0 0">
    </a-gltf-model>
</a-marker>
```

You can also try using echoAR (full disclosure, I'm involved in this project). There is a [whole section that build's AR.js for you](https://docs.echoar.xyz/ar.js/deploy-experience). You can use it entirely or just see how to build your HTML file from the results you are getting there.