# arjs not displaying gltf model

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to make a simple arjs application based on the tutorials on the website, specifically [this one](https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/ar-js-the-simpliest-way-to-get-cross-browser-ar-on-the-web-8f670dd45462)

I've been able to successfully swap out other gltf models for new codes, but whenever I try to use my own models they do not display in the application.

I've tested my model in the viewer at https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and it shows up fine.

My code is below.

```
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <!-- we add detectionMode and matrixCodeType to tell AR.js to recognize barcode markers -->
    <a-scene embedded vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;">

    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="animated-asset" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="bimmer" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jaggre/consortium/master/compresso.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

    <a-marker type='barcode' value='2'>
        <a-entity 
        animation-mixer
        gltf-model="#bimmer"
        scale="4 4 4">
    </a-marker>

    <a-marker id="animated-marker" type='barcode' value='6'>
        <a-entity
            animation-mixer
            gltf-model="#animated-asset"
            scale="2 2 2">
        </a-entity>
    </a-marker>

    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: It could be that your model is too big, and maybe you have to scale it down...

Answer (score 1):

Check in your console for any Cross origin Resource Sharing errors - sometimes if your website is hosted via http or set up differently it doesn't work. see https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/asset-management-system.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors and https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server . If you just use the file:// protocol as you are testing it may not work.

Other things you could try is moving the model's `a-entity` tag outside of the marker tag to see if the marker class is having an effect on it. perhaps check the A-frame inspector (Ctrl Alt I) and poke around if it's just displaying in the wrong place.

Update: [gltf2.0 not showing in ar.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056118/gltf2-0-not-showing-in-ar-js-project) seems like a similar question. Perhaps try it's answers too.